# Using Distinct in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sqlite

Please find the query given below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        reco_index_content_code,
        reco_index_content_name,
        reco_index_content_url
    FROM tbl_reco_index_contents
    WHERE
        reco_index_user_action_at_select = 1
        AND user_profile_number = 1
```

I need to select `reco_index_content_name` as distinct.

How should the above query be modified, in order to accomplish that, such that there are no duplicate `reco_index_content_name` rows ?

Comment: what will you do with the following `reco_index_content_code`? eg, select only the lowest code?

Comment: In the event that there are duplicates, which row do you want returned. Note that "Don't care" is often indicative of poor design.

Comment: @Strawberry -- I understand, but this I am doing as a temporary fix for a demo. It can be any row.

Comment: Can it be *any value* then? Use constants for the other columns: `SELECT DISTINCT '' AS reco_index_content_code, reco_index_content_name, '' AS reco_index_content_url FROM ...`

Answer (score 1):

The standard solution is documented and uses an uncorrelated subquery as follows:

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT grouping_id
            , MIN(ordering_id) min_ordering_id 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY grouping_id  
     ) y
    ON y.grouping_id = x.grouping_id
   AND y.min_ordering_id = x.ordering_id;
```

Comment: can you please let me know how to apply this to my query above? Sorry, I do not have much expertise here.

Comment: perhaps not, but I think you can figure it out ;-)

Comment: ok.. my_table = tbl_reco_index_contents ,grouping_id=reco_index_content_code. What is ordering_id?

Comment: according to your description, grouping_id is `reco_index_content_name`