# SQL - MAX function returning incorrect data

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, groupwise-maximum

I am trying to get with each question that having max seq_no record, but it is returning wrong data.

Here is query:

```
SELECT id, attempt, seq_number, question
FROM question_states
WHERE attempt = 374
AND seq_number IN ( SELECT MAX(seq_number) FROM question_states WHERE attempt = 374 GROUP BY question)
GROUP BY question, id
```

I have one table name as questions, structure is given below:-

```
id--seq_number--attempt--question
1 --0     --374  -- 130
2 --0     --374  -- 130
3 --1     --374  -- 130
4 --2     --374  -- 130
5 --1     --374  -- 131
```

Why this query returns 2 records against question `130` ? and if I remove the `GROUP BY id` then returns wrong data.

Comment: Have a look around for similar questions

Comment: yeah I have looked many questions - but no fruit.

Comment: Because "id" is different, i guess

Comment: but it has first group by on question!

Comment: Did you checked if this part of query giving you expected result. "SELECT MAX(seq_number) FROM question_states WHERE attempt = 374 GROUP BY question"

Comment: @Suleman if you have 2 columns in GROUP BY clause, you will get full permutation between 2 set of values in the result

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Distinct in SQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007229/using-distinct-in-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, attempt, seq_number, question
FROM question_states qs 
INNER JOIN (SELECT question, MAX(seq_number) seq_number 
            FROM question_states WHERE attempt = 374 GROUP BY question
           ) AS A ON qs.question = A.question AND qs.seq_number = A.seq_number 
WHERE attempt = 374
```

**OR**

```
SELECT id, attempt, seq_number, question
FROM (SELECT id, attempt, seq_number, question
      FROM question_states WHERE attempt = 374
      ORDER BY question, seq_number DESC
     ) AS A 
GROUP BY question
```

Comment: In your 2nd answer don't you have the risk that the fields in the SELECT that aren't in the GROUP BY or aggregate function, are not guaranteed to be consistent? Has the use of the ORDER BY in the derived table been documented to overcome that problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the subquery, since you used group by, it will return two values '2' and '1'.
and in the main query since you used 'IN' statement, it will return all the data with field seq_number and attempt = 374

try

select max(seq_number), id, attempt, question from question_states group by seq_number  ORDER by seq_number DESC limit 1